# Create a nested object json file using bash

Tags: json, bash

I have a small bash script that scours through a directory and its subs (media/) and adds the output to a json file.

The line that outputs the json is as follows:

```
printf '{"id":%s,"foldername":"%s","path":"%s","date":"%s","filename":"%s"},\n' $num "$folder" "/media/$file2" "$fullDate" "$filename" >> /media/files.json
```

The json file looks like this:

```
{"id":1,"foldername":"5101","path":"/media/5101/Musicali10.mp3","date":"2015-08-09:13:16","filename":"Musicali10"},
{"id":2,"foldername":"5101","path":"/media/5101/RumCollora.mp3","date":"2015-08-09:13:16","filename":"RumCollora"}
```

I would like it group all files in a folder and output something like this

```
[   {  
  "id":1,
  "foldername":"5101",
  "files":[  
     {  
        "path":"/media/5101/Musicali10.mp3",
        "date":"2015-08-09:13:16",
        "filename":"Musicali10"
     },
     {  
        "path":"/media/5101/RumCollora.mp3",
        "date":"2015-08-09:13:16",
        "filename":"RumCollora"
     }
  ]   },   
{  
  "id":2,
  "foldername":"3120",
  "files":[  
     {  
        "path":"/media/3120/Marimba4.mp3",
        "date":"2015-08-04:10:15",
        "filename":"Marimba4"
     },
     {  
        "path":"/media/3120/Rumbidzaishe6.mp3",
        "date":"2015-08-04:09:10",
        "filename":"Rumbidzaishe6"
     }
  ]
}
]
```

My question is how to create a json file that has nested "files" objects? I want each "foldername" to have a nested list of of files. So far I am only able to output each file as an array using the printf statement above.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried, and how did it fail? A simple [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command line may be all you need.

Comment: My question is how to create a json file that has nested "files" objects. I want each "foldername" to have a nested list of of files. So far I am only able to output each file as an array using the printf statement above. I don't have jq but can install it on the Ubuntu server if that is the way to go.